# Error: Initializer Element is not constant (c language)

Tags: c, floating-point, constants

This is a .h file to store formulas but it gives me the ERROR you see at the tittle on line #16(below the string). I'm a beginner and the error says is not constant so I though of putting "const" before the "float" but it doesn't work either way.

```
#ifndef FORMULAS_H_INCLUDED
#define FORMULAS_H_INCLUDED

float a;
float Pi=3.1415926536;
float r;
float b;
float c;
float h;




char formula_volume_cube[100] = "Formula for the Volume of a Cube: V=a*a*a";
const float volume_cube=(a*a*a);



#endif // FORMULAS_H_INCLUDED
```

Any help will be appreciated. THANK you for YOUR time.

Comment: Perhaps include the error in your post, so people can more easily help you out. I'm not that familiar with `c` but I guess the problem is that `a*a*a` is not a constant expression. Perhaps try to make `a` a const value. Otherwise you'll have to define the content of volume in the `.c` file.

Comment: "(a*a*a)" is just a simple multiplication problem and its not involved in the problem . I know this because when i take out that  portion from the .h file and put it into the actual code(.c file) It runs perfectly

Comment: but its easier to have all formulas in one .h file so I don't have to rewrite everything again

Comment: Try and declare `a` const, which doesn't make much sense since it hasn't been set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global variables in C can only be initialized with *compile-time constant expressions*, and that is a very narrow class of expressions. It essentially only comprises literals or expressions involving literals:

```
float a1 = 1.5;                   // OK
const float a2 = 2.5 * 10 / 300;  // Also OK
```

An expression that identifies another global variable is not a compile-time constant expression:

```
// float a3 = a2;                 // Error!
```

C is just not expressive enough for this. This is all for the sake of simplicity. For example, C does not distinguish between `const float b1 = 2.5;` and `extern const float b2;`. The variable `b1` is no "more const" than `b2`, but only `b1`'s value is known to the compiler, whereas `b2`'s value is not known — it may be set only by a different translation unit, and without any ordering. So there's no way to make one constant "more constant" than the other. The simple solution in C is that *no* id-expression can be used as a compile-time constant.

(C++, by contrast, allows global variables to have dynamic initializers. This introduces a whole set of ordering concerns if one global variable's initializer depends on another global variable. C has none of those problems.)

Comment: okay but in my case i want the user to input the value of a and multiply it by the value of 3 and that's why I put a*a*a .Will that still work?because it works fine in the actual .c file

Comment: @AlucardVP22: That has nothing to do with anything. You can always *change* the value of a global variable later. We are *only* talking about the initializer here.

Comment: @AlucardVP22: You may be confused about how C works. C is imperative, not declarative. You execute statements. You *don't* once and forever declare `c` to be the value of `a * a * a` and have the value of `c` change as `a` changes (like an Excel formula). That's what *functions* are for: `float volume(float length) { return length * length * length; }`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. And also i want to ask how come when I put the code in .c file works and in the .h file does not

Answer (score 0):

The message

> Error: Initializer Element is not constant

pretty much says it all

```
float a;
```

is not declared as a constant (it can change as the program runs), so

```
const float volume_cube=(a*a*a);
```

cannot be a constant, as it is based on the non-constant `a`.

Comment: Would it make a difference if `a` was declared `const`, though?

Comment: @Eric J. it doesn't make a difference if i take out the "const" , I had it without the const before the float and it gives me the same error